# Ember Dynamically Create Models from Other Models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**Goal**

I am trying to list a series of events grouped by date ranges. My approach is to create an EventGroup model which has a list of Events. Instead of defining the EventGroups server side or with fixtures I would like to create the groups dynamically on the client side (and keep them in sync as events are updated).

**Setup**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Event = DS.Model.extend(
{
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    date_start: DS.attr('string'),
    date_end: DS.attr('string'),
    // ...
    // Example of how an event can be classified into an event group
    date_group: function( )
    {
        var groups = {'thisWeek': {start: moment().startOf('week'), end: moment().endOf('week')},
                      'nextWeek': {start: moment().add(1, 'week').startOf('week'), end: moment().add(1, 'week').endOf('week')},
                      'thisMonth': {start: moment().add(2, 'week').startOf('week'), end: moment().endOf('month')}
                      };
        return function( )
        {
            var date = this.get('date_start');
            for( group in groups )
            {
                if( date <= group.end && date >= group.start )
                {
                    return group;
                }
            }
            return date.getMonth();
        }.property('date_start');
    }(),
});

App.EventGroup = DS.Model.extend(
{
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    date_start: DS.attr('string'),
    date_end: DS.attr('string'),
    events: DS.hasMany('event')
});

App.EventGroup.FIXTURES = [];
```

**Approaches**

I can create/update an event group model from the init method of an event model however this does not seem very clean and does not encapsulate the logic very well.

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend(
{
    // ...
    init: function( )
    {
        // update EventGroup models
        this.store.createRecord('eventGroup',
        {
            // Proper event group creation data/code...
        });
    }
});
```

Creating an observer seems like an OK approach however I am not sure where to set this up. I don't think creating an observer in the EventGroup model makes sense.

```
App.EventGroup = DS.Model.extend({
    onEventAdded: function( )
    {
         // Proper event group creation code...
    }.observes('App.Event')
});
```

Extending the Application Adapter seems to be the cleanest approach but I have not had any luck getting this to work. I would like to override createRecord and if it is an Event, create/update the corresponding EventGroup.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend(
{
    init: function( )
    {
        console.log('init')
    },
    createRecord: function( )
    {
        console.log('create record')
        this._super();
    },
    find: function( )
    {
        console.log('find')
        this._super();
    }
});
```

Only 'init' is ever logged. 'create record' and 'find' do not show up in the console.

Of course if there is a better way to go about this, I'm all ears!

Comment: So it looks like this question hasn't gotten very many views/answers. Any suggestions on making the question more palatable to the masses?